# Convert String Extension to Linq

Tags: c#

I have the following String extension:

```
    public static int LineFromPos(this string S, int Pos)
    {
        int Res = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Pos; i++) {
            if (S[i] == '\n') {
                Res++; }
        }
        return Res;
    }
```

Is it possible to convert this to a single code line using maybe linq?

Comment: I am curious as to why this is being downvoted.

Comment: Why did you start at 1?

Comment: @Stilgar without being able to read other people's minds, but there's no research effort evident

Comment: Is this just counting the number of `\n` characters _up to_ `Pos`? (and I'm guessing starting at `1` because it's essentially counting the number of lines. So if no `\n` is found, it's still 1 line long to start)

Comment: What possible research could have been done? It is not like you can Google this or just invent it if you don't know LINQ. I suspect that people are downvoting it because there is no reason to convert it to LINQ but that does not make the question bad.

Comment: I am trying to find the line number (1 based) of the identifier character in the string.

Comment: @MDMoura `identifier character` ?

Comment: @Stilgar "possible research" would include actually learning some LINQ and making an attempt at it, that's why I downvoted.

Comment: So he got 7 downvotes for not knowing LINQ? Interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
return (1 + s.Take(Pos).Count(c => c == '\n'));
```